# how to update one dropdown based on the other dropdown in JSF2 and primefaces?

Tags: java, jsf

How to implement cascading dropdowns in JSF using query (fetching data from database) not through using arraylist?

If I select one value in the first dropdown it should populate second dropdown with specific items. How to do this in JSF?

Any help will be highly appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this [drop-down example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/pprSelect.jsf).

Comment: I was following this example but it is implemented through arraylist not using queries

Comment: Retrieve your queries result into ArrayList, than apply this example.

Comment: how to do this? Can u give me any example?  I am new to JSF. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am using two different beans